# Manipulate with With and without - scope of variables

Tags: plotting, function-construction, scoping

I am struggling with some basic concepts:

Why this works:

```
plts = (mm[#]*Sin[x]) & /@ Range[5];
With[
 {localplot = plts /. {(mm[#] -> mv[#]) & /@ Range[5]} // Flatten},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[localplot, {x, 0, 10}],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{mv[#], 0, Subscript[a, #]}, 0, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[5])
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

and this one does not

```
plts = (mm[#]*Sin[x]) & /@ Range[5];
Manipulate[
 Plot[plts, {x, 0, 10}],
 Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ ({{mm[#], 0, Subscript[a, #]}, 0, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[5])
  ]
 ]
```

Isn't `mm` just a symbol, so why do I have to make the symbol local with `With`?

Comment: I believe that Manipulate will "localize" the manipulate variables (which amounts to renaming them in a special way). So, in your second case, the symbol `mm` in the Global namespace isn't "seen" by the Manipuate, because it didn't show up explicitly in the body of the Manipulate. In the first case, however, With does all of its symbol replacements before anything else happens, so when Manipulate gets evaluated, it does "see" the symbols and applies the localization to them.

Comment: Effectively what @lericr says, combined with the fact that `With` doesn't consider `Manipulate`to be a scoping construct itself, and therefore doesn't try to avoid any name collisions with the variables of `Manipulate`.